# MaterializeCss Table with fixed head and aligned column content

Tags: html, css, materialize, css-tables

I am trying to get a table with a fixed head so that the rest of the body is scrollable. The thing is I need it to be done with [materializeCss Table](http://materializecss.com/table.html) .

I can achieve this, and I've done so, however every solution that does it makes the table columns with different chars be unaligned, check this image:
[image: unaligned content]

This one has the borders so you can see the problem:

[image: with border]
This is the CSS that i'm using and produces said result(the `scroll` class is in the table):

```
.scroll {
  border: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}    
.scroll tr {
  display: flex;
}    
.scroll td {
  flex: 1 auto;
}    
.scroll thead tr:after {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}    
.scroll thead th {
  flex: 1 auto;
  display: block;
}    
.scroll tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc(80vh - 100px);
}
```

My question: **How to align the content by column WITH fixed head and materialize?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some testing I figured it out, essentially if you use the same CSS as me, you only need to replace the  `flex: 1 auto;` properties to `flex: 1;` (remove the auto and it aligns perfectly).

---

Furthermore, if you need the head to be perfectly aligned to the body (there will be a small offset due to the scrollbar, just add a `padding-right` property to `thead tr{}` that matches the scroll bar width)